# Segmentation Fault in C program that read a text file

Tags: c

I´m writing a small C program that reads a text file and the prints it´s contents on screen. I do get the prints, but at the end of the printing I get a segmentation fault. Also, if I uncomment the atoi function I only get the first print and then a segmentation fault.Can anyone tell me what my error is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> /* For mode constants */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h> /* For O_* constants */


int sudoku[9][9];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if(argc!=2){
        printf("error en numero de parametros, el directorio de archivo de sudoku.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    char *directorio = argv[1];
    //printf("el directorio es: %s \n", directorio);
    int fp;
    fp=open(directorio,O_RDWR);
    if(fp<0){
        printf("error al leer el archivo");
        return -1;
    }   

    char *data = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fp,0);

    if (data == -1) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<81 ; i++){
        printf("data : %c \n",data[i]);
        //int val =atoi(data[i]);
    }

    if ((munmap(data,4096)) != 0) perror("!mumap failed");
    fclose(fp);


}
```

Comment: `atoi` takes a character array (string), in your case you want to use single characters. This will most likely crash since there isn't a null in the end, unless the sunspots are favorable. In any case you won't get what you want (a single character's numeric value)

Comment: As to the crash without atoi, is your file surely at least 81 bytes long? What does the debugger say what's wrong?

Comment: My file just contains this string `534678912672195348198342567859761423426853791713924856961537284287419635345286179` it is exactly 81 characters long. I don´t really know how to get the debugger going. I´m totally new to C

Comment: Honestly, it sounds to me like you would be better off with `data[i] - '0'` rather than `atoi` anyway, assuming you fixed all the other items wrong in the posted code.

Comment: Strongly suggest compiling with all warnings enabled.  For gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'.   The posted code does not cleanly compile.  There are several warnings raised by the compiler.  Several of those warnings are very serious.  For instance, passing a 'int' to the fclose()' function. The parameter has to be the returned 'FILE *' from a call to fopen(), not the 'int' from a call to open()

Comment: regarding this line: 'if (data == -1) {'   'data' is defined by: 'char *data = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fp,0);' (which I suspect has some parameter problems) I.E. a char*, not a 'int'  Per the man page, use: '(void *) -1)' rather than just '-1'.

Comment: the posted code is not using any of the 'ipc' functions, not any of the 'semaphore' functions; so why are those headers being #included in the code?

Comment: The problem was in the fclose() I changed it to   ` close(fp)` and it works now. Thanks to everybody, I learned a lot from the comments.

Comment: the global variable: 'int sudoku[9][9];' is being declared, but never used.   Why is the command line supplied file path/name being opend O_RDWR when it is never written to?  Suggest using: 'O_RDONLY'   the code should not contain any 'magic' numbers other than -1, 0 and 1.  All other numbers should be #define'd with meaningful names and those names used throughout the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you have experience a segfault is because you have used `fclose()` to close a file that you have opened with `open()`.

`int fclose(FILE *stream)` is the function prototype for `fclose()` and `int close(int fildes)` is the prototype for `close()`.

What this means is that `fclose()` is expecting a FILE pointer but is receiving the argument `fp` which you've declared as an int, this is what is causing your segfault. The program is trying to access the memory **address** location of the value of fp which it doesn't have the correct permissions to access, thus the segfault.

I've compiled and ran your program replacing `fclose()` with `close()` and I no longer had any segfault issues.

Regarding your `atoi()` call, this as has been explained by other posters, is due to `atoi(const char *str)` requiring a char pointer as its argument. What `atoi()` is receiving is not a char pointer but a char variable therefore it doesn't get terminated by the `'\0'` character, that is the cause of your segfault with the `atoi()` function.

Since you are operating on one character at a time it makes more sense to use `int val = data[i] - '0'`. Chars in C are integer types and the C standards do not guarantee that the character representation of '0' will be the same across all implimentations, for example the number zero on my machine is 48, '1' is 49 and 2 is 50. The C standards do however state that no matter the representations of numbers as chars, that for the characters '0' to '9', they will all be a value of 1 higher than the number before it. Therefore doing a small bit of char math you can work out that `'2' - '0' = 2` as '2' is 50 (on this system) and '0' is 48.

Answer (score 5):

> if I uncomment the atoi function I only get the first print and then a
>   segmentation fault.

The reason for that is the atoi takes argument as char *, its prototype is

> int atoi(const char *nptr);

When a char is passed as argument the ascii value of the char is treated as an address, the value will be (0-255). You dont have permission to access these locations and hence segmentation fault.